# How to trigger Javascript function in a page loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, I have a page which consist of 2 text input field and a DIV.

The 1st input text field is where the user will input a data and the 2nd input text field is a readonly. After pressing the Enter key in the 1st input text field, a separate page will load inside the DIV based on what is inputted that is queried in a database.

The problem is I need to pass a value to the 2nd input field which is the readonly coming also from the same data queried. Please help me...

Sample Code: I made a separate app since this is basically what should happen in my app.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function loadNow(p,d){
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById(d).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",p,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="Input Here"
        onkeyup="if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {
        loadNow('testnewpage1.php?r='+this.value,'loadHere1'); }" />
        <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" readonly />
        <div id="loadHere1">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

testnewpage1.php

```
<?php
    require('conn.php');
    $r=$_GET['r'];
    $query = mssql_query("select somefield from sometable where reference='$r'");
    $data = mssql_fetch_array($query);
    echo "
    <script>
        input2.value='$data[somefield]';
    </script>
    ";
?>
```

EDIT: Even alert(); function is not working.

Comment: Is the data being loading into the readonly textbox the same data you are expecting your query to produce? Or will the query output have more data than necessary?

Comment: Yeah, it's actually the same query, but the query will output 1 or more row so I just need that one same value from the rows to display. Well, I figured how to make it work to my liking, anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to use a `<span>` for the outputted text field and re-display it again within the new page.

Here is the final code if anyone is interested:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadNow(p,d){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById(d).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",p,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="Input Here"
    onkeyup="if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {
    loadNow('testnewpage1.php?r='+this.value,'spaninput'); }" />
    <span id="spaninput">
        <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" readonly />
    </span>
    <div id="loadHere1">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**testnewpage1.php**

```
<?php
    require('conn.php');
    $r=$_GET['r'];
    $query = mssql_query("select somefield from sometable where reference='$r'");
    $data = mssql_fetch_array($query);
    echo "<input type='text' id='input2' name='input2' value='$data[somefield]' readonly />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a quick and dirty solution:-

```
<?php
    require('conn.php');
    $r=$_GET['r'];
    $query = mssql_query("select somefield from sometable where reference='$r'");
    $data = mssql_fetch_array($query);
    echo "
    <script>
        document.input2.value='$data[somefield]';
    </script>
    ";
?>
```

Tthis would be more preferred :-

Index.php's javascript :-

```
 <script>
        function loadNow(p,d){
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById(input2).value=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",p,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

testnewpage1.php:-

```
<?php
    require('conn.php');
    $r=$_GET['r'];
    $query = mssql_query("select somefield from sometable where reference='$r'");
    $data = mssql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $data[somefield];
?>
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and it's not working, even alert(); is not working. The second suggestion is not applicable since the form is in format already. It can't be change.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript when you page loads, you could use the document.ready function and put your code in there, document.ready is called when the DOM is ready which can be prior to images and other external content is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    /* code here */ 
});
```

*edit*
For the alert function not working, you need to include the Jquery script in your code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still not working. Can you give me sample? Of using the document.ready function? I tried putting my code there, it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried putting the jquery in your script? document ready usually runs the script when the page loads with no problems

Comment: I've put it inside the script tag, inside my <script> tag. It's not working.